# How to allow access to backend only from frontend in Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, devops

I have an application, React for frontend, Node.js for backend. The application will be uploaded to Digital Ocean, how can I hide the backend so that users have access only to the frontend.

Comment: The question is a bit broad but I suppose that essentially you want to restrict access to the backend. You cannot hide your backend because it still needs to be accessible from your frontend application, and since it's a webapp it means it should be accessible from anywhere. That said, you can *secure it* in many different ways, but at the very least your application needs to handle the notion of authentication & authorization. This is a very broad subject but I hope it gives you a hint.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If docker use:
You can split the frontend and backend into different containers, for the frontend to make access from outside, and the backend to hide behind the network inside the Docker. Your frontend will call backend over Docker's internal network by application name.

You can also hide the frontend and backend using nginx. Use nginx to access the frontend inside your docker network. It turns out that access from the outside will only be to nginx.

read more https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: The problem with this is that frontend pages are generally rendered client side. Meaning the frontend will be communicating to the backend from the outside. Therefore no internal access such as from the backend to the database, which are both server side. So when the frontend app makes a call to localhost for example, localhost will be relative to your client and not your server. The same applies to using application names. They mean nothing outside your server. A possible exception to this might be server side rendering, SSR. But I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you cannot hide your backend is that React uses Client-side rendering by default. This means that the client uses the browser to make calls to the backend. There are ways to make your backend secure such as using an access token or putting a Web Application Firewall in front of the server. 
I believe there are ways to make your frontend in react to work as a Server-Side rendering, but as default and as a Single Page Application will do Client-Side rendering.

This article may help you to understand: 
https://www.toptal.com/front-end/client-side-vs-server-side-pre-rendering